# How can I graph from the data set?

Tags: r, plot

```
x <- del_time[,c('arrivaltime')][1:4]
x
y <- del_time[,c('prop_arrdelay')][1:4]
y

barplot(x,y)
```

Here are the results

```
[1] "Early"   "Evening" "Morning" "Night"  
> y <- del_time[,c('prop_arrdelay')][1:4]
> y
[1] 0.9083699 0.4830701 0.3752655 0.5393416
> barplot(x,y)
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am getting an error here, how can I fix it?

Comment: You are calling function `c()` twice without needing it, `c('arrivaltime')` and `'arrivaltime'` are the same vector. You only need the combine function `c()` when you have 2 or more vector elements.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the formula interface to `barplot`.

```
x <- c("Early",   "Evening", "Morning", "Night"  )
y <- c(0.9083699, 0.4830701, 0.3752655, 0.5393416)

barplot(y ~ x, ylim = c(0, 1), las = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you increase the range for y since the graph is bigger than the axis?

Comment: @loms Use `ylim = c(0, 1)`.